# Importing Python files from S3 to Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr, hadoop-streaming

I want to include compiled proto classes in my mapreduce and figured the easiest way to do so would be to zip the required python files as a tar.gz and upload them to S3.

I came across [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324186/5685105) and followed these steps to create the archive file. I then used `-cacheArchive` argument to distribute the file to the clusters.

Using boto to launch an EMR job here is what my configuration looks like:

```
Steps=[{
    'Name': '...',
    'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER',
    'HadoopJarStep': {
        'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
        'Args':
            ['hadoop-streaming',
             '-files', 's3://myBucket/mapper.py,'
                       's3://myBucket/reducer.py',
             '-mapper', 'mapper.py',
             '-input', 's3://myBucket/input/',
             '-output', 's3://myBucket/output',
             '-reducer', 'reducer.py',
             '-cacheArchive', 's3://myBucket/required.tgz#required']
    }
}]
```

mapper.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

sys.path.append('./required')
from primitives_pb2 import Variant

for line in sys.stdin:
    # DO THINGS
```

I am getting the following error when EMR.

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:332)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:81)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:452)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:171)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)

The mapreduce seems to work fine when running it locally, so I don't believe there is an error with the way I have written either `mapper.py` or `reducer.py`.

Comment: `subprocess failed with code 1 `. The Python code died because some other code died

Comment: @cricket_007 it's due to the import statement. I am testing on a simple word count EMR and it runs fine without the import.

Comment: Okay. FWIW, I feel like PySpark might work better than MR streaming, depending on your workload